# Preselect radio input in Vue component in complex v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue component that handles multiple forms, retrieving and submitting data from and to the Gravity forms API. Everything works perfectly, except for preselecting the default value for the radio input (which is presented as a toggle).

Here is an abridged version of the component:

```
<template>
    <form :id="gf" ref="form">
        <div
            v-for="field in fields"
            :key="field.id"
            :id="`field_${field.id}`"
            :class="`field field__${field.type}`"
        >
            <div v-if="field.type == 'radio'">
                <div v-for="(choice, index) in field.choices" :key="choice.value">
                    <input
                        type="radio"
                        :id="`gf_${index}_${field.id}`"
                        :name="`input_${field.id}`"
                        :value="choice.value"
                        v-model="entries[`input_${field.id}`]"

                        // insert way of checking input with isSelected == true here
                    >
                    <label :for="`gf_${index}_${field.id}`">{{ choice.text }}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        formId: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
        },
        formName: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
        },
    },

    data() {
        return {
            fields: '',
            form: '',
            entries: {},
        }
    },

    mounted: function() {
        this.getForm()
    },

    methods: {
        getForm() {
            const vm = this
            axios
                .post('path/to/gravity/forms/api', {
                    id: vm.formId,
                })
                .then(result => {
                    vm.form = result.data
                    vm.fields = result.data.fields
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
        },

    },
}
</script>
```

Note that the values are submitted to the form in the correct way, but only when clicked on. I need to find a way to automatically check the input based on the data retrieved from the api.

The API returns a simple array for each radio input, the default input (as defined in Gravity forms) reads as follows:

```
isSelected: true
text: "Email"
value: "Email"
```

Note: I have read through many answers to related issues on Stack Overflow, but the solution invariably involves hardcoding values into data, which is not an option. Also the entry must be added in the format above for the API to understand the submission (code for this not relevant so not included).

All suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Put the correct initial value into the variable you're binding with `v-model`

Comment: @RoyJ Thanks, sorry if I'm not understanding you, but how would i go about doing that given that I won't ever know the field.id in advance? Can this be done within the loop?

Comment: You have to do it when you receive the data from the API. In your JavaScript, not in your view, for each field, find the selected choice and set the value in `entries`

Comment: I see, thank you. I was hoping to avoid this because it's going to result in some code spaghetti digging through the fields, but it would seem to be the only option.

Comment: you can have the data either in `entries['input_${field.id}']` (as you specified with v-model) or using the `isSelected` that is provided. Those are two separate objects, and Vue can't magically intuit where the value _may_ reside.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks. The idea was to use one to update the other.

Comment: but it's not a good idea to attempt that during the render phase. You need to either set the `entries` values after the data is loaded or use the `isSelected` and process the data when it is being sent. Alternatively, you can also create a `computed` var that merges these two, but that has some caveats too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the pointers from Daniel and Roy J, I was able to resolve this reasonably cleanly by adding a method to loop through the incoming fields and update the entries object accordingly.

```
   getForm() {
        const vm = this
        axios
            .post('/path/to/gf/api', {
                id: vm.formId,
            })
            .then(result => {
                vm.form = result.data
                vm.fields = result.data.fields
                vm.getRadios()
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    },
    getRadios() {
        let radios = this.fields.filter(field => field.type == 'radio')
        radios.forEach(radio => {
            let selected = radio.choices.find(
                choice => choice.isSelected == true
            )
            this.entries[`input_${radio.id}`] = selected.value
        })
    },
```

I also added

```
 :checked="choice.isSelected"
```

on the template, along with the v-model as before.

Answer (score -1):

If you're not using `entries` for anything else, you don't need it at all. You don't need to `v-model`, you just want to set `checked`, which is pretty straightforward:

```
:checked="choice.isSelected"
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    fields: []
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.fields = [
          {
            id: 1,
            type: 'radio',
            choices: [
              {
                isSelected: false,
                value: 1,
                text: 'one'
              },
              {
                isSelected: true,
                value: 2,
                text: 'two'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            type: 'radio',
            choices: [
              {
                isSelected: true,
                value: 1,
                text: 'three'
              },
              {
                isSelected: false,
                value: 2,
                text: 'four'
              }
            ]
          },
        ];
      }, 500);
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchData();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<form id="app">
  <div v-for="field in fields" :key="field.id" :class="`field field__${field.type}`">
    <div v-for="(choice, index) in field.choices" :key="choice.value">
      <input type="radio" :id="`gf_${index}_${field.id}`" :name="`input_${field.id}`" :value="choice.value" :checked="choice.isSelected">
      <label :for="`gf_${index}_${field.id}`">{{ choice.text }}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I need 'entries' for the submission of the form (as mentioned above, the code of my form is abridged to just the relevant parts), so while this works with no v-model present, it does not solve my problem.